# Why can't set child width and height as same as the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Parent element is div whose width is 300px and height is 40px, child element is input .

```js
myinput = document.getElementById("e2");
myinput.style.cssText ='width:100%;height:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;'
```

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="e1"><input id="e2" type="text" /></div>
```

I want to set child width and height  as same as the parent,
`myinput.style.cssText ='width:100%;height:100%;'` will make the child bigger than parent.

Comment: Your `input` tag is never closed.

Comment: It is no use to close .

Comment: Have you tried setting ```padding``` to ```0``` and playing around with the border?... Etc...

Comment: [`* { box-sizing: border-box }`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/); Paul Irish on ["* { Box-sizing: Border-box } FTW"](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/); [International box-sizing Awareness Day](https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/)

Comment: You need to read about the very basics called *box model*.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Your code was like `<div><input </div>`. That is simply completely invalid HTML.

Comment: I had fixed my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
myinput.style.cssText ='width:100%;height:100%;box-sizing: border-box;'
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `input` has `border-width: 2px;` so you have to set input's `border-width:0px;` as follow

```js
myinput = document.getElementById("e2");
myinput.style.cssText ='width:100%;height:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;border-width:0px;'
```

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="e1"><input id="e2" type="text" /></div>
```